# "While the family was away" and "while the family went away"

Tags: word-usage

There's a dog that stayed at a boarding facility while its family went on vacation. When you are talking about the dog, do these sentences mean the same thing?

> The dog stayed at the boarding facility while the family **was** away.
>
> The dog stayed at the boarding facility while the family **went** away.

I am not sure if the sentences mean the same thing, or the second sentence sounds as if the dog was boarded only during the time the family was moving away from home.

Comment: In the UK we would normally say it had stayed at the kennels. Boarding facility sounds too grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences do not have the same meaning. Your interpretation of the second one is correct and an unlikely scenario. A native English speaker would say the first one if they wanted to convey the information in your very first sentence.
However, in British English it is also possible to say

> The dog stayed at the boarding facility while the family **were** away.

As [Merriam Webster](https://learnersdictionary.com/qa/Family-Singular-or-Plural-collective-nouns-usage-grammar) says "In American English, "family" will almost always be used with a singular verb. In British English, it may be used with a singular or a plural verb depending on whether the speaker feels that "family" is being described as a unit or as a group of individuals"